# Erro 418 Wordpress, Redirecionamento SSL e plugin W3

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, redirecionamento, ssl

Comprei um certificado SSL para meu blog e então fui editar o `.htaccess` para incluir o redirecionamento 301.

Recebi como resposta que estava havendo excesso de redirecionamentos e então verifiquei o arquivo e encontrei os comandos criados pelo plugin `W3`, usado para controle de memória, uso de memória do navegador para aceleração, etc.

Eis os comandos:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wo$
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%$
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}$
```

Quero entender o que o Plugin está fazendo ao usar todos estes comandos, mas especificamente o seguinte está me parecendo muito esquisito:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wo$
```

O que significa o uso desse comando do método POST neste ponto do .htaccess e para onde ele está redirecionando esta informação?

Como posso desabilitar o controle desses comandos no plugin W3 sem desabilitar o plugin como um todo?

Porque não posso editar o .htaccess que o plugin não permite.